# Facebook NativeAd example not showing anything

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-ads-api, native-ads

I followed instruction https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-native to implement nativeAd in my app. According to this example, example ad should look like this

[image]

Mine look like this

[image]

> MainActivity

```
private NativeAd nativeAd;
    private LinearLayout nativeAdContainer;
    private LinearLayout adView;

    private void showNativeAd() {
        nativeAd = new NativeAd(this, "placement id");
        nativeAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError error) {
                // Ad error callback
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                // Ad loaded callback
                if (nativeAd != null) {
                    nativeAd.unregisterView();
                }

                // Add the Ad view into the ad container.
                nativeAdContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.native_ad_container);
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                // Inflate the Ad view.  The layout referenced should be the one you created in the last step.
                adView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.native_ad_layout, nativeAdContainer, false);
                nativeAdContainer.addView(adView);

                // Create native UI using the ad metadata.
                ImageView nativeAdIcon = (ImageView) adView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_icon);
                TextView nativeAdTitle = (TextView) adView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_title);
                MediaView nativeAdMedia = (MediaView) adView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_media);
                TextView nativeAdSocialContext = (TextView) adView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_social_context);
                TextView nativeAdBody = (TextView) adView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_body);
                Button nativeAdCallToAction = (Button) adView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_call_to_action);

                // Set the Text.
                nativeAdTitle.setText(nativeAd.getAdTitle());
                nativeAdSocialContext.setText(nativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
                nativeAdBody.setText(nativeAd.getAdBody());
                nativeAdCallToAction.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());

                // Download and display the ad icon.
                NativeAd.Image adIcon = nativeAd.getAdIcon();
                NativeAd.downloadAndDisplayImage(adIcon, nativeAdIcon);

                // Download and display the cover image.
                nativeAdMedia.setNativeAd(nativeAd);

                // Add the AdChoices icon
                LinearLayout adChoicesContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ad_choices_container);
                AdChoicesView adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(MainActivity.this, nativeAd, true);
                adChoicesContainer.addView(adChoicesView);

                // Register the Title and CTA button to listen for clicks.
                List<View> clickableViews = new ArrayList<>();
                clickableViews.add(nativeAdTitle);
                clickableViews.add(nativeAdCallToAction);
                nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(nativeAdContainer, clickableViews);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                // Ad clicked callback
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
                // Ad impression logged callback
            }
        });

        // Request an ad
        nativeAd.loadAd();
    }
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="me.skyse.disablefingerprint.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/native_ad_container"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <include layout="@layout/native_ad_layout" />




</LinearLayout>
```

> navtive_ad_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/native_ad_unit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/native_ad_icon"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/native_ad_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sponsored_label"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="Sponsored"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="10sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ad_choices_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.facebook.ads.MediaView
        android:id="@+id/native_ad_media"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/native_ad_social_context"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:lines="2"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="10sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/native_ad_body"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:lines="2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/native_ad_call_to_action"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#4286F4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="11sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What i am doing wrong. Most of the code is copied directly from the example

Comment: You have set the test device in activity (`AdSettings.addTestDevice`) and the `facebook_app_id` in strings?

Comment: No but i tried native Ad template and it worked fine.